# Properly automate a docker script in Python

Tags: python, bash, docker

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8) to build a TF image classifier, I have a bash shell in which I run a Docker image with the following command:

```
docker run --name fooldocker -it -v $HOME/tf_files:/tf_files/ gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

And then in this docker image I run my Python script:

```
python /tf_files/label_image.py /tf_files/myimages
exit
```

It works.

But now, **I need to automate these commands in a Python script**. I tried :

```
p = Popen(['docker', 'run', '--rm', '--name', 'fooldocker','-it', '-v', '$HOME/tf_files:/tf_files/', 'gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel'], stdout=PIPE)
p = Popen(['docker', 'exec', 'fooldocker', 'python', '/tf_files/label_NES.py', '/tf_files/NES/WIP'])
p = Popen(['docker', 'kill', 'fooldocker'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p = Popen(['docker', 'rm', 'fooldocker'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Leading to this error after Popen #2 is run :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create $HOME/tf_files: "$HOME/tf_files" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$HOME` cannot be evaluated in this single quotes string. Either try doublequotes, or evaluate the variable beforehand and put it into the command string.

Also: If you set shell=True, you don't split your command into a list:

```
p = Popen('docker kill fooldocker', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because Popen didn't interpret `$HOME` to your home path.
and it is the string `$HOME` and pass to docker command which not allow `$` in a volume name.

maybe you can use `subprocess` module for convenience, for example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("echo $HOME", shell=True)
```

it interpreted `$HOME` if `shell=True` specified.

Comment: Popen is a part of the subprocess module ;)

Comment: oh, yes, I forgot it belongs to `subprocess` too. 
Use wrappered functions too often :|